# Change virtualmachine and virtualdesktop to virtual-machine and virtual-desktop

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I've seen many multi-word tags without hyphen in superuser.

The last ones being [virtualmachine](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/virtualmachine) and [virtualdesktop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/virtualdesktop).

Should they be changed this way?:

- [virtualmachine](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/virtualmachine) => [virtual-machine](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/virtual-machine)
- [virtualdesktops](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/virtualdesktops) => [virtual-desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/virtual-desktop) (or [virtual-desktops](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/virtual-desktops)?)

On the different sites there are different tags.

Should be singular or plural? I'm leaning towards singular.

Answer (score 1):

#### Here's a listing of all of the `*virtual*` tags. *( except SO )*

- Super User

  ```
   13 × virtualmachine
   12 × virtualbox
    2 × virtualization
    1 × virtual
    1 × virtual-desktop
    1 × virtualdesktops
    1 × virtualdub
    1 × virtual-machine
    1 × virtualpc
  ```
- Server Fault

  ```
   11 × virtual
  192 × virtualization
   53 × virtual-machines
   31 × virtualbox
   22 × virtualpc
   13 × virtualhosts
    6 × msvirtualserver
    3 × virtual-memory
    3 × virtualserver
    2 × virtualdirectories
    2 × virtual-domains
    2 × virtualdrive
    2 × virtual-drive
    2 × virtualhost
    2 × virtual-pc
    1 × application-virtualizati
    1 × virtual-connect
    1 × virtual-harddrive
    1 × virtual-machine
  ```
- Stack Overflow

  ```
  168 × virtualization
   41 × virtual-machines [Marc: merged into virtual-machine]
   11 × virtual-memory
   11 × virtual-directories [Marc: merged into virtual-directory]
    1 × virtualdirectory [Marc: merged into virtual-directory]
    6 × virtual-directory
    5 × virtual-machine
    1 × virtual-disk
    1 × virtual-drive
  [Marc: also tidied up virtual-pc and virtual-server]
  ```

Comment: virtualdub should stay as-is, name of the application does not have a space or dash.

Comment: I will clean up the SO one's later this morning.